# Supress logs while running Azure Powershell commands

Tags: azure, powershell, logging, azure-powershell, flags

I an running Azure Powershell commands where I will be adding the Network rules to storage account, diagnostic logs storage account and Keyvault and I am using the following Azure commands.

- Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule
- Add-AzKeyVaultNetworkRule

And I am getting lots of logs while executing this in my powershell. Not only these commands, but most of the Azure commands will output some logs into the powershell console, the above two are just examples.

**I want to know if there is any flag that we can add at the end of the Azure powershell commands so that it won't output any logs or output minimal logs into the powershell console.**

Comment: I saw a similar question a few days ago but I am not able to find it now. IIRC, one of the solution suggested there was to pipe your Cmdlet with `$null`. Something like `Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule ...parameters | $null`. Can you try that?

Comment: Sure, I will try and report the results here.

Comment: No, It is not working it is throwing error saying that Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline. Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
+ ...  $diagnosticLogStorageAccountName -IPAddressOrRange $EgressIP | $null

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Try this instead: https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/10/07/4-ways-to-send-output-to-null-in-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Gaurav Mantri, For the last blog you posted. its gave the output as per op's requirement for the logs. Posting it as an answer to beneficial for other community members.

***We have also tried the same using the [***blog***](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2017/10/07/4-ways-to-send-output-to-null-in-powershell/) to see the logs if its appear or not using pipeline with `| Out-Null` and can able to not getting any logs for this***. *Also there are another 3 ways as mentioned in that blog*.

We have tried with below `cmdlts`:-

```
Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName "rgname" -Name "cloudtest*****" -IPAddressOrRange "10.0.0.0/7","28.2.0.0/16" |Out-Null
```

***PLEASE CHECK MY OUTPUT SCREENSHOT FOR REFERENCE:-***

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you Ajay, I am unable to check the blog. Thanks for doing it. And Thanks Gaurav for the blog link.